# Get values ​from an xml using xpath in apache camel

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

I am trying to retrieve values ​​from a soap service response, that is coming like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:consultaCEPResponse xmlns:ns2="http://cliente.bean.master.sigep.bsb.correios.com.br/"> 
             <return>
                 <bairro>Jardim das Acácias</bairro>
                 <cep>04707900</cep>
                 <cidade>São Paulo</cidade>
                 <complemento2></complemento2>
                 <end>Avenida Roque Petroni Júnior 1089</end>
                 <uf>SP</uf>
              </return>
        </ns2:consultaCEPResponse>
     </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm using apache camel for it.However, when I apply xpath to use only what is between the return tag, it brings everything on a single line with no tag, and for this reason, I cannot set properties

What am I getting:

```
INFO 15:23:47.808 - Jardim das Acácias04707900São PauloAvenida Roque Petroni Júnior 1089SP
```

What I want to receive:

```
<bairro>Jardim das Acácias</bairro>
<cep>04707900</cep>
<cidade>São Paulo</cidade>
<complemento2></complemento2>
<end>Avenida Roque Petroni Júnior 1089</end>
<uf>SP</uf>
```

Then after, do something like:

```
.setProperty("bairro",xpath("/bairro//text()"))
```

This is my code:

```
public class RotaEnviaPedidos {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:pedidos?noop=true")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("POST"))
            .to("https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .transform().xpath("//*[local-name()='return']//text()")
            .log("${body}");
        }
    });

    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000000000);
    context.stop();
}
```

}

**PS**: Maybe it is due to the use of 
Then do something like:

Maybe it is due to the use of '.convertBodyTo (String.class)'
 But if I don't use this command, it brings the following error:

```
 org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream] due org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 202; Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with apache-camel. What if you use just `//*[local-name()='return']`, without `text()` or instead use `node()`. What happen?

Comment: yeah! It worked !! I'm newbie at apache camel too. I also don't know what's the purpose of 'text()'
I was wondering that was to get the text inside the tag...

Comment: `text()` represent the text(string) of node. You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

can you try the below:

```
@Override

   public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:pedidos?noop=true")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("POST"))
        .to("https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .transform().xpath("//*[local-name()='return']")
        .log("${body}");
    }
```